# RestSharp serialization error

Tags: c#, restsharp

Any idea why i am getting serialization error? I tried it with other web methods and it worked. Just this particular.

```
public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient
            {BaseUrl = BaseUrl, Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(AccountSid, SecretKey)};

        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

        if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            throw response.ErrorException;
        }
        return response.Data;
    }
```

This is the object.

```
 public class Order
{
    public Order() { }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double SoldPrice { get; set; }
    public double Fees { get; set; }
    public String BuyerEmail { get; set; }
    public String BuyerName { get; set; }
}
```

This is my JSON.

```
"[{\"ProductName\":\"Demo  Hinges\",\"SoldPrice\":700.0,\"Fees\":21.0,\"Size\":\"\",\"BuyerEmail\":\"\",\"BuyerName\":\"\"}]"
```

I am getting this error.

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'RestSharp.JsonArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.
   at RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer.FindRoot(String content)
   at RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer.Deserialize[T](IRestResponse response)
   at RestSharp.RestClient.Deserialize[T](IRestRequest request, IRestResponse raw)}

Comment: The json is a type of JsonArray mentioned in the error and you are trying to cast it into a Dictonary or an object change the deserialization to accept an Array instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Order is reserved word. I changed it to SaleOrder and it worked like a charm.